# Unit Test MVC controller

Tags: unit-testing, model-view-controller, controller

I am new to test MVC controllers and I need help. I searched on SO for last two days but I think I am missing something. Please see sample code and test below.

Here is code that needs to be tested

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public async Task AddBook(Book book)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity uci = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
        if (book.Id == Guid.Empty)
        {
            book.Id = Guid.Parse(uci.FindFirst(ClaimType.Book).Value);
        }

        string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(book);
        await BookAPIService.Current.AddBook(jsonData);
    }
```

My test

```
[Test]
        public async Task  TestMVC()
        {
            Book b = new Book();
            b.Name ="n";
            b.Id="123";

            //Arrange
            var mockController = new Mock<BookController>();

            var classUnderTest = mockController.Object;
            IPrincipal principal = null;
            principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("user"),
            new string[0]);
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
            classUnderTest.HttpContext.User = principal;// Error Null Object
            await classUnderTest.AddBook(b);//// Error Null Object
            classUnderTest.GetBook(b.Id);
        }
```

Comment: If the controller is the class under test then create an instance of it. You usually don't mock the class under test.

Comment: There also seems to be some design issues with having static api services in your controller.

Comment: There iss eparate Int tets for BookAPIService.Current.AddBook. I am creating object mockController  but not able to set context correctly.

Comment: Have a look here http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/unit-testing/creating-unit-tests-for-asp-net-mvc-applications-cs

Comment: Also check the testing section here http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/recommended-resources-for-mvc